# Converting any file to TIFF format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, fs, tiff

I’m working on file uploader application.
I have a file which I receive from client in PDF, DOC, DOCX, JPG formats and i need to convert them to TIFF format and to save each page in a separate file.
pls advice the best way to do it.

is there any library you can suggest for doing it?

Comment: Each format is going to have its own library.  You might find a common library that wraps up others, but there isn't an option to convert "any file".  You might find it easier to execute command line utilities like GhostScript as a child process to your Node.js script.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following library from the [**Photopea**](https://github.com/photopea/photopea) project:

https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js/

It can be simple installed with npm:

```
npm install utif
```

and follow some examples on github.